# Playing All Videos on Tor Safely

Tags: anonymity, information-leaks

I am wondering how to play videos on Tor without compromising my ip. All help appreciated. Everything that I have read so far says doing so can compromise the system.

Answer (score 2):

Any video that you can play inside TorBrowser should play safely, just make sure you don't install any additional plugins. This allows for example youtube to work almost all the time. There is no anonymity-preserving way to play videos that require Adobe's Flash player plugin currently and you should never trust the plugins that some websites offer you to play their videos.

Comment: Sebastian, Please have a litlle patience with me. First off, Thank-You for responding. Now don't I have to add a plug-in to play videos? When you set up a new browser you have to download adobe or somethong to see the video. Why would this be diff? Or are you saying any add ons, or plug ins, or anything inside Tor is safe for use? Break it down like I have a concussion. I will not take it personally. Once again Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

It's different because YouTube and some other video hosting sites support HTML5 video playback, which requires no plugins to function. It's just an open Web standard. That said, protocols like WebRTC that use methods like UDP hole punching via STUN may leak your actual IP address unless you're transparently proxying all your traffic through Tor or turn off that particular flag in your browser (or use a browser that already does this, like TorBrowser).